# apache poi setting up a value on a specific cell on an excisting excel file

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

[Here is my excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqGPe.jpg)

I have a function on my java code that will open an excisting excel file, and what i want to do is once i click print it will open up the excel file with a value from my text fields. (Heres my code for this)[and Here is what im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C4jF.jpg)
helps will really be appreciated. thanks in advance

```
btnPrint = new JButton("Print");
    btnPrint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            try{

                FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("FormTemplates\\Book1.xls"));   
                HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
                HSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 

                Cell cell = null;

                cell = my_worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue((String)txtNo.getText());
                cell = my_worksheet.getRow(2).getCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue((String)txtNo.getText());
                cell = my_worksheet.getRow(3).getCell(2);
                cell.setCellValue((String)txtNo.getText());

                input_document.close();


                FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Popoy\\Desktop\\Poy ITS\\FORMTEMPLATES\\UpdateXLS.xls"));
                my_xls_workbook.write(output_file); 
                output_file.close();
            }
            catch(Exception q){
                q.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do you expect? Your code writes `(String)txtNo.getText()` in `C2`, `C3` **and** `C4`. But `C2:E4` is merged. So only **one** value is possible in `C2:E4` (`C2`). And what is actually `(String)txtNo.getText()`? I suspect it is `1`?

Comment: case closed arigatou gozaimasu ! <3